# I accidentally chmod -R +x on a directory. How do I restore the correct permissions?

Tags: permissions, files, chmod

Well, to be specific, it was `chmod -R 755`. Now every file is executable, which I don't want.
I am thinking that I should look at the first two bytes of each file for the `#!`, but will this cover everything? Should I instead use `file` to look at everything and base my decision on that? Or, more likely, is there an even better way to do this?

What is the preferred way to recursively go through a directory and set -x on files that are not 'supposed to be' executable?

Comment: Did you do this at `/` or another directory?

Comment: @gvkv: Not `/`, a directory completely owned by me.

Comment: @Larry in the future you should probably use some variant of +x rather than raping all permissions, and possibly causing writes on all files.

Comment: @xenoterracide: Agreed. What I really wanted was to give group same permissions as me (which did end up happening!), I just didn't do enough thinking before I typed.

Comment: How many files are we talking about?  How many should be executable?  Is there any way to tell from the file names?

Comment: @David: About 10k files, with about 300 or so that were supposed to be executable. Only indication in the file name is shell scripts end with .sh and perl scripts end in .pl, but those I could tell from the `#!` at the start anyways.

Comment: Related, though I hesitate to call it a duplicate: [Setting execution right to whole directory - is it good or bad idea?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24389)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no magic bullet here. The permissions carry information which is not always redundant.

If you'd done this in a system directory, your system would be in a very bad state, because you'd have to worry about setuid and setgid bits, and about files that are not supposed to be world-readable, and about files that are supposed to be group- or world-writable.

In a per-user directory, you have to worry about files that aren't supposed to be world-readable. No one can help you there.

As for executability, a good rule of thumb would be to make everything that doesn't look like it could be executed, be nonexecutable. The kernel can execute scripts whose first two bytes are `#!`, ELF binaries whose first four bytes are `\x7fELF` where `\x7f` is the byte with the value 12, and a few rarer file types (a.out, anything registered with `binfmt_misc`). Hence the following command should restore your permissions to a reasonable state (assumes bash 4 or zsh, otherwise use `find` to traverse the directory tree; warning, typed directly into the browser):

```
for x in **/*; do
  if ! [ -f "$x" ]; then continue; fi # skip all but regular files
  case $(head -c 4 "$x") in
    "#!"??) :;; # skip script
    "\x7fELF") :;; # skip ELF executable
    *) chmod a-x "$x";;
  esac
done
```

Note that there is a simple way to back up and restore permissions of a directory tree, on Linux and possibly other unices with ACL support:

```
getfacl -R >saved-permissions
setfacl --restore=saved-permissions
```

Comment: Thanks! Fortunately, I think everything falls into these two categories. If this misses anything, I can deal with it later.

Comment: Bear in mind that `**/*` requires `globstar`.

Comment: I'd recommend two changes to this script. One, use `find` rather than globstar; two, instead of looking at the head, use the `file` command to see what it is and branch from there.

Comment: @Shadur `find` is less reliable than `globstar`, `globstar` is preferable in almost every case.

Comment: @ChrisDown Whoa! find and globstar each have their good and bad points in terms of reliability, portability, clarity, efficiency, …

Comment: @Gilles Preferable as in "if you have it, it's far superior", not only is it faster, it's also more reliable (and doesn't have unexpected SNAFUs).

Comment: @ChrisDown Not always. With `**/*`, you need to remember to use `--` in case a filename in the current directory begins with `-`. And you risk running into the command line length limit. While `find | …` is dodgy because of newlines in filenames, `find -exec` avoids most reliability issues. P.S. This is getting off-topic; continue in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) if you want.

Answer (score 8):

I believe you will want something like

`find dir -type f -exec chmod ugo-x '{}' +`

This looks for all regular files, recursively in dir, (it excludes directories, and devices) and removes the executable bit.

I would start here, and then work my way towards making files that are supposed to be executable, executable.

The following should work exactly as you asked for ( it will find all regular files, grep them for #! and then remove the x bits if not found )

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -L #! | xargs chmod ugo-x
```

possibly a better version of the above (less pipes)

```
find . -type f -exec grep -L #! '{}' + | xargs chmod ugo-x
```

Comment: Make that `grep -L '^#!'` at least (the quotes are necessary, and `^` restricts to matching at the beginning of the line), but it's still too permissive as it matches `#!` on any line. Using `xargs` will fail with file names containing spaces or quoting characters; use `xargs -d '\n'` (requires GNU `xargs`).

Answer (score 0):

Well, without a shebang line, the file will be executed as a shell script, nominally with `/bin/sh`.  You're idea is a good start and on the assumption that the directory in question doesn't contain mission-critical files there probably isn't much risk to executing some `grep` and `chmod` combo.  You may encounter false positives, i.e., files with a shebang line that are not meant to have their executable bit set but without knowing more information on the purpose of what's in the directory, only you can decide whether that poses a significant existential threat to your system and/or data.

Comment: I'm not worried so much about false positives as false negatives. There are binaries that I don't think start with `#!`.