# Reset ownership to default on opensuse 13.2

Tags: permissions, system-recovery

Hi guys I did something very stupid to my system

```
Chmod 777 -R /
```

After that everything disappeared including the mouse pointer
I'm was able to log in now but things are so corrupted I can't use su and so on .
I did search on the suse website and found that many people had faced this problem unfortunately with no help .
Is there any guideline to put things back on the right track ?? 
What's the default permissions for any Linux system and how to know them??

Comment: It's not the same question , mine is more general and the answer for that question is not general enough to fit here, however I'm very interested in how he was able to find the answer out. There should be some references.

Comment: @RobertL Definitely not a duplicate. You don't want to give every single file execution permissions!

Comment: Similar, but recovery will be a little different: [Broken system after chmod -R 644 /](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194644/broken-system-after-chmod-r-644)

Comment: @Gilles I found your link very helpful and perhaps even find the answer in it . I will try it out .