# Linux/CentOS - can't su after changing ownership

Tags: linux, centos, su

I mistakenly changed ownership of all files on a CentOS system from root to my login account. I can login but if I `su` I get:

```
su: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted
```

I don't need the system to be fully functional but I do need to `su` into it for a few days. Since I can log in and I do have permission to the entire system, it seems like the `su` function can't write to something with groups. If I change this then it will.

Does anyone know what permissions I need to change?

Comment: No, `su` is complaining because the `setgroups()` call fails (not being run with uid=0). And since this is a security problem, `su` decides to exit instead. I suggest you to boot a recovery/install media and restore the file ownerships/permissions.

Comment: note also that restoring ownership and/or permissions is almost impossible (i.e. impossible unless you have a complete list of what every file's owner, group, and perms are supposed to be).   You may find it faster, easier, and a lot less frustrating to backup your data in e.g. `/home` and your config files from `/etc` and re-install from scratch.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/wrongly-set-chmod-777-problems

Comment: I wish I could reboot this server. It's at a COLO that doesn't let us have boot level access. Thanks anyway.