# Accidentally changing permission of '/' directory to 'chmod 660 '

Tags: chmod

After executing `$ sudo chmod 660 /`, I can't login with any of the users besides root. How can I restore the permissions ?

Comment: have you tried to change it back with `chmod 750 /` while being logged in as `root` ?

Comment: related: [wrongly set chmod 777 /](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/wrongly-set-chmod-777-problems)

Answer (score 5):

As root

```
chmod 755 /
```

restores that to the default permissions.  If you'd done

```
chmod -R 664 /
```

then you'd have to reinstall.

Comment: even if you did `chmod -R 664 /` you could avoid the full re-installation,e.g. on rpm-based system you could verify the file modes with `rpm -V`

Comment: no - root wouldn't be able to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried chkperm utility?

https://gitlab.com/chkperm/chkperm/wikis/home

I think you can use it on fresh linux installation to get the correct permission, then boot your server into recovery mode and use chkperm to fix these permissions to the original state.