# Some problem to sudo

Tags: debian, sudo

I am having problem in using sudo command
i am using debian os in my pc.

Whenever i type sudo commands,i got this errors:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin "sudoers_policy"
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

Comment: What are the permissions of `/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so`? It should be `644`

Comment: If you have changed permissions on not only that file but a larger set of files, you have a real problem now (not just with `sudo`).  See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/wrongly-set-chmod-777-problems